# Ocelot Disable SSL validation with "DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator"

Tags: .net-core, ssl-certificate, ocelot

I have issue after adding self-signed certificate, requests are blocked at gateway with message

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Then I found that is possible to disable validation with adding this in configuration

```
"DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator": true
```

But still have same issue and same error.

Answer (score 4):

I've just started using **Ocelot** and I was getting the *"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."* error and that's how I ended up here.

As @capcom923 mentioned  the directive works fine or at least solved the issue I was facing on my Dev Environment.

Just in case I put here the relevant parts of my configuration.json

```
"Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Tareas/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "myDebServerName",
          "Port": 444
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/tareitas/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT", "GET" ],

      "DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator": true
    }
```

I hope this might add some value for the ones facing the same situation.

Comment: Sebastian after one hour searching I finally find where that option is put in the ocelot file! Thank you for being accurate and actually sharing the exact content.

Comment: How to make it work for wss too? Seems like for wss this validator is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The directive below as you mentioned works fine for me.

```
    "DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator": true
```

I use the Ocelot 16.0.1. And the doc is here
https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, late to the party.

It may well be that your downstream services are also having the **invalid cert** issue. Ocelot will only deal with its initial pass on, it is down to the next http caller(s) to deal with it.

So we use Refit using NET Core and have code like this in our registration (for the services that ocelot is calling)

```
return services.AddHttpClient(name, configureClient)
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate2, arg3, arg4) => true
        };
    });
```

And we hit this if we have an octopus variable defined that says **ignoreinvalidsllcerts** (so in test only!!!!)

This is refit/c#/core code but may help as long as you are creating an HttpClient!